# Jest - Testing Certificate Validation

Tags: node.js, jestjs

Seeking some advice on the best way to handle unit testing with Jest of some Certificate handling functions.

I have a validation function that validates a passed in certificate (via and API Call) against a root CA and another that uses the above certificate to encrypt some data before passing it back to the caller.

Thinking about how I could test this reliably I came up with the idea of using OpenSSL to create my own CA and the required test certificates. I could save them in the projects tests directory as files and having a test case to check that were valid before further use of them as mocks for the functions I'm testing.

My thinking here is that the test certificates could be saved into source control with no issues and would be robust test cases.

Does that sound like a reasonable approach or is it overkill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is that the unit tests should only test your implementation in both positive and negative scenarios and should mock all API calls. This way you can run your tests against every code change and they won't fail if the service is not available.

This is an example solution outline:

```
import implementation from "./implementation";
import certificate from "./cerficiates/genuine";
import request from "request-library";

jest.mock("request-library");

describe("Certificate validation", () => {
  describe("validate", () => {
    describe("returning negative response", () => {
      beforeAll(() => {
        let result;
        beforeAll(() => {
          request.post.mockClear();
          request.post.mockResolvedValue({
            body: "invalid certificate",
          });
          result = implementation.validate(certificate);
        });

        it("should have made a post request with certificate", async () => {
          await result;
          expect(request.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            "http://validate.certificate.com",
            {
              body: certificate,
            }
          );
        });

        it("should return error", async () => {
          await expect(result).rejects.toEqual(new Error("invlid certificate"));
        });
      });
    });

    describe("returning positive response", () => {
      let result;
      beforeAll(() => {
        request.post.mockClear();
        request.post.mockResolvedValue({
          body: "valid certificate",
        });
        result = implementation.validate(certificate);
      });

      it("should have made a post request with certificate", async () => {
        await result;
        expect(request.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
          "http://validate.certificate.com",
          {
            body: certificate,
          }
        );
      });

      it("should return true", async () => {
        expect(await result).toBe(true);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

This solution follows the FIRST principles of unit testing

✅[F]: Fast as don't rely on any service local/remote. Can't fail because
of test timeout/service unavailability

✅[I]: Doesn't depend on anything

✅[R]: Repeatable as it reproduces the same results each time you run it

✅[S]: Self-validating as it won't rely on anything to check if it has to pass or fail

✅[T]: Timely as you can write it before/along with your implementation

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I was thinking to use OpenSSL test certificates as I didn’t want to store any valid certificates in my repository. It does add a potential point of failure and some overhead but increases security.

Comment: My answer is about how to unit-test the JavaScript function that validates the certificates, not the actual certificate, as that’s how I interpreted your question. And in case you don’t want to store the certificates in your repository you’ll jut have to change the import of the certificates to some mock value